# Make Unity aware of System.Runtime.InteropServices to build project for HoloLens using HoloToolKit

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, hololens, interopservices

First of all, thank you guys so much, your posts, and answers here have been invaluable in my HoloLens development efforts!

**So, here is my issue:**

- Old project developed when HoloToolKit was first starting out.
- Now want to implement spatial mapping and Sharing
- Manually imported just the Sharing folder of the HoloToolKit with
  Meta files into Unity
- Press play and everything works great after changing several scripts
  to look for the HoloToolKit namespace as opposed to HoloToolKit.Unity
- Drop in the prefab for sharing
- Test and this works great from the editor (see the connections on the
  server no prob)
- Build the project - all hell breaks loose!
- 647 errors appear in the editor and nothing in visual studio
- All of these are from the SDK
- All have the same error as follows:
- error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'HandleRef' does not exist 
  in the namespace 'System.Runtime.InteropServices' (are you missing 
  an assembly reference?)
- **What I have tried:**
- Import from the package only the Sharing goodies .... this breaks  my
  project in that all serialized gameobjects become reset. Not 
  feasible to reset all those game objects....
- Copy in the System.Runtime.InteropServices.dll file into plugins
  folder in the assets folder - no joy
- Copy in the csc, gmcs, mcs, and smcs files (whatever they are) into
  the project and try to rebuild - no joy.
- pulled my hair out and banged my head on the rock and the hard place
  until barely conscious - no joy.

Any help you guys have would be absolutely 100% appreciated. Thanks in advance guys, and happy coding!

Answer (score 1):

need to copy in the CrossPlatform folder from the HoloToolKit as it exposes a class file called MetroHandleRef which, as the name implies, handles the refs exposed by InteropServices.  Thanks guys!